# Consolidating a data table in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am working on a small data analysis tool, and practicing/learning Scala in the process. However I got stuck at a small problem.

Assume data of type:

```
X   Gr1     x_11    ... x_1n
X   Gr2     x_21    ... x_2n
..
X   GrK     x_k1    ... x_kn
Y   Gr1     y_11    ... y_1n
Y   Gr3     y_31    ... y_3n
..
Y   Gr(K-1)     ...
```

Here I have entries (X,Y...) that may or may not exist in up to K groups, with a series of values for each group. What I want to do is pretty simple (in theory), I would like to consolidate the rows that belong to the same "entity" in different groups. so instead of multiple lines that start with `X`, I want to have one row with all values from `x_11` to `x_kn` in columns.

What makes things complicated however is that not all entities exist in all groups. So wherever there's "missing data" I would like to pad with for instance zeroes, or some string that denotes a missing value. So if I have (X,Y,Z) in up to 3 groups, the type I table I want to have is as follows:

```
X   x_11    x_12    x_21    x_22    x_31    x_32
Y   y_11    y_12    N/A     N/A     y_31    y_32
Z   N/A     N/A     z_21    z_22    N/A     N/A
```

I have been stuck trying to figure this out, is there a smart way to use List functions to solve this?

---

I wrote this simple loop:

```
for {
  (id, hitlist) <- hits.groupBy(_.acc)
  h <- hitlist
} println(id + "\t" + h.sampleId + "\t" + h.ratios.mkString("\t"))
```

to able to generate the tables that look like the example above. Note that, my original data is of a different format and layout,but that has little to do with the problem at hand, thus I have skipped all steps regarding parsing. I should be able to use `groupBy` in a better way that actually solves this for me, but I can't seem to get there.

Then I modified my loop mapping the `hits` to `ratios` and appending them to one another:

```
for ((id, hitlist) <- hits.groupBy(_.acc)){
  val l = hitlist.map(_.ratios).foldRight(List[Double]()){
    (l1: List[Double], l2: List[Double]) => l1 ::: l2
  }
  println(id + "\t" + l.mkString("\t"))
  //println(id + "\t" + h.sampleId + "\t" + h.ratios.mkString("\t"))
}
```

That gets me one step closer but still no cigar! Instead of a fully padded "matrix" I get a jagged table. Taking the example above:

```
X   x_11    x_12    x_21    x_22    x_31    x_32
Y   y_11    y_12    y_31    y_32
Z   z_21    z_22
```

Any ideas as to how I can pad the table so that values from respective groups are aligned with one another? I should be able to use `_.sampleId`, which holds the "group membersip" for each "hit", but I am not sure how exactly. ´hits´ is a List of type `Hit` which is practically a wrapper for each row, giving convenience methods for getting individual values, so essentially a tuple which have "named indices" (such as `.acc`, `.sampleId`..)

(I would like to solve this problem without hardcoding the number of groups, as it might change from case to case)

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you require. Could you post example outputs for the table you posted (the one you want and the one you have?)

Comment: @gzm0 added more info, specifically those example outputs you asked for

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a contrived example, but I think you can see where this is going:

```
  case class Hit(acc:String, subAcc:String, value:Int)

  val hits = List(Hit("X", "x_11", 1), Hit("X", "x_21", 2), Hit("X", "x_31", 3))
  val kMax = 4
  val nMax = 2

  for {
    (id, hitlist) <- hits.groupBy(_.acc)
    k <- 1 to kMax
    n <- 1 to nMax
  } yield {
    val subId = "x_%s%s".format(k, n)
    val row = hitlist.find(h => h.subAcc == subId).getOrElse(Hit(id, subId, 0))

    println(row)
  }

//Prints
Hit(X,x_11,1)
Hit(X,x_12,0)
Hit(X,x_21,2)
Hit(X,x_22,0)
Hit(X,x_31,3)
Hit(X,x_32,0)
Hit(X,x_41,0)
Hit(X,x_42,0)
```

If you provide more information on your `hits` lists then we could probably come with something a little more accurate.

Comment: hmm thanks for the answer but there might have been some misunderstanding, the `x_ij` are the actual values, not some subaccession. Btw I added more info as you asked for

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this problem with the following code, I am putting it here as an answer in case someone else runs into a similar problem and requires some help. The use of `find()` from Noah's answer was definitely very useful, so do give him a +1 in case this code snippet helps you out.

```
val samples = hits.groupBy(_.sampleId).keys.toList.sorted
for ((id, hitlist) <- hits.groupBy(_.acc)) {
  val ratios =
    for (sample <- samples)
      yield hitlist.find(h => h.sampleId == sample).map(_.ratios)
      .getOrElse(List(Double.NaN, Double.NaN, Double.NaN, Double.NaN, Double.NaN, Double.NaN))
  println(id + "\t" + ratios.flatten.mkString("\t"))
}
```

I figure it's not a very elegant or efficient solution, as I have two calls to `groupBy` and I would be interested to see better solutions to this problem.

Comment: You might not want to accept your solution if you want better ones, so people see your question is not resolved yet.